# phpMyadmin error "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

After I installed the latest version of **PHP 7.3.4** and **MySQL Community Server 8.0.15** I faced this error on my **phpmyadmin 4.7.7**:

> Warning in .\libraries\config\FormDisplay.php#661 "continue" targeting
>   switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
>
> Backtrace
>
> .\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php#444: include()
>   .\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php#322:
>   Composer\Autoload\includeFile(string
>   'F:\apps\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer/../../\libraries\config\FormDisplay.php')
>   Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass(string
>   'PMA\libraries\config\FormDisplay')
>   .\libraries\config\PageSettings.php#76: spl_autoload_call(string
>   'PMA\libraries\config\FormDisplay')
>   .\libraries\config\PageSettings.php#230:
>   PMA\libraries\config\PageSettings->__construct( string 'Navi_panel',
>   string 'pma_navigation_settings', )
>   .\libraries\navigation\Navigation.php#66:
>   PMA\libraries\config\PageSettings::getNaviSettings()
>   .\libraries\Header.php#425:
>   PMA\libraries\navigation\Navigation->getDisplay()
>   .\libraries\Response.php#260: PMA\libraries\Header->getDisplay()
>   .\libraries\Response.php#273: PMA\libraries\Response->_getDisplay()
>   .\libraries\Response.php#432: PMA\libraries\Response->_htmlResponse()
>   PMA\libraries\Response->response()

Anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: This is probably an issue with a non backward-compatible change in PHP. I would advice you to update to the latest version of PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs by PHP backward-compatible.

Updating to the latest version, for me was **4.8.5** resolved the issue.

Answer (score 13):

Edit PHP script in the file **FormDisplay.php**
At this line *660*, I found this code in this path

`$ /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config/FormDisplay.php`

[image]

```
case 'select':
     $successfully_validated = $this->_validateSelect(
     $_POST[$key],
     $form->getOptionValueList($system_path)
     );
     if (! $successfully_validated) {
         $this->_errors[$work_path][] = __('Incorrect value!');
         $result = false;
         continue;
    }
    break;
```

Update it as per below suggestion

```
case 'select':
     $successfully_validated = $this->_validateSelect(
     $_POST[$key],
     $form->getOptionValueList($system_path)
     );
     if (! $successfully_validated) {
         $this->_errors[$work_path][] = __('Incorrect value!');
         $result = false;
         break;
    }
    break;
```

[image]

Reload PHPMyAdmin and your issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same, and fixed it by editing the php script **FormDisplay.php**.

On line 661, replace **continue** with **break** (keep the semi-colon).

If you do edit, you'll need sudo access, but back up the original one first.

Reload the page. Hope that helps.

Comment: this works, but -1 because an update to the new version is a better solution

Comment: still relevant in 10.3.22-MariaDB and PHP version: 7.3.14 running on Raspbian Buster 4.19.97